# Calculating the result of a formula by matching the numbers

Tags: r, string, match

I have two data frames as follows:

```
a1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4), type = c(463,479, 5357,4771), amount = c(110,95,2100,23))
a2 <- data.frame(AltID = c(101:103), Calculation = c('[479]+[4771]','[5357]/([479]*[463])','([463]-[4771])/[5357]'))

> str(a1)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID    : int  1 2 3 4
 $ type  : num  463 479 5357 4771
 $ amount: num  110 95 2100 23

> str(a2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ AltID      : int  101 102 103
 $ Calculation: Factor w/ 3 levels "([463]-[4771])/[5357]",..: 2 3 1
```

The numbers in "BRACKET" that appear in "Calculation" column in "a2" are all available in the column "type" in "a1", which has the corresponding value in the "amount" column in "a1".

The goal is to add a column to "a2" that uses the "Calculation" formula in each row of "a2", match the numbers with a1$type, and use the proper arithmetic operations to generate a single number that corresponds to each "AltID" row in "a2".

For the example above,

```
a2$result <- rep(0,3)
```

and I would like to get:

```
a2$result[1] = 95+23
a2$result[2] = 2100/(95*110)
a2$result[3] = (110-23)/2100
```

I was wondering if there is a smart way for doing this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's probably a better way to do whatever you're doing but I would need to know a lot more about your real starting point and end goals.

Here's how I would go about your problem as stated:

First I'm going to replace your `type` numbers in `a1` with valid variable names by pasting `x` on the front. Then I stick them in their own environment so that we can use these variables later without cluttering up the workspace:

```
a1$var = paste0("x", a1$type) # make variable names
a1_env = new.env()            # create new environment
                              # fill new environment:
mapply(FUN = assign, x = a1$var, value = a1$amount, MoreArgs = list(envir = a1_env))
```

Now we're going to replace the bracketed numbers in `a2` with the same variable names. This means we delete the close brackets `]` and replace the open brackets with `"x"` to match the variable names created in `a1_env`:

```
a2$Calculation = gsub(pattern = "\\[", replacement = "x", x = a2$Calculation)
a2$Calculation = gsub(pattern = "\\]", replacement = "", x = a2$Calculation)

a2
#   AltID        Calculation
# 1   101         x479+x4771
# 2   102  x5357/(x479*x463)
# 3   103 (x463-x4771)/x5357
```

Last, we just need to parse and evaluate the calculation column in the environment we created where these variables are defined:

```
a2$Result = sapply(a2$Calculation, FUN = function(x) {
     eval(parse(text = x), envir = a1_env)
})

a2
#   AltID        Calculation       Result
# 1   101         x479+x4771 118.00000000
# 2   102  x5357/(x479*x463)   0.20095694
# 3   103 (x463-x4771)/x5357   0.04142857
```

This answer comes with an obligatory warning:

```
> fortunes::fortune(106)
If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)
for(i in 1:nrow(a1)) {
  a2$Calculation <- str_replace_all(a2$Calculation, as.character(a1$type[i]), as.character(a1$amount[i]))}
a2$Calculation <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", a2$Calculation)
a2$Total <- sapply(a2$Calculation, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
a2
#  AltID   Calculation        Total
#1   101         95+23 118.00000000
#2   102 2100/(95*110)   0.20095694
#3   103 (110-23)/2100   0.04142857
```

In this case, a for loop works because it saves the last replacement and uses it for the next iteration. We replace each value step by step with `str_replace_all`. Next we eliminate the brackets with `gsub`. And lastly we use `eval(parse(text=x))` to go from a text string of the operations to the actual values.

Follow Gregor's general caution with regard to text parsing. Usually when someone needs it for a function call, somewhere in the pipeline they backed themselves into a programming corner that could have been avoided.